# Sed command to replace numbers between space and :

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with a records like the below

```
FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255
```

I want to  remove values between space and :

```
FIRST:SECOND:THREE:FIVE:SIX
```

with code

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*,:*' '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, file
```

Comment: `tr -d '0-9 ' < file`

Comment: a Field Separator is a regular expression, not a range expression, so `-F '[[:space:]]*,:*'` means your input will be split into fields separated by each occurrence of `a string comprised of zero-or-more spaces followed by a comma followed by zero-or-more colons`. Can you have numbers, spaces, or colons anywhere else in the field (e.g. as part of a field like `SECOND`)?

Comment: Field may also have numbers like this                                                            
      FIRST_1 1: SECOND_2 2: THREE_33 4: FIVE_2 255: SIX 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -F' [0-9]*(: *|$)' -vOFS=':' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
```

tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/\s+[0-9]+(:|$)\s*/\1/g' file
```

Explanation of awk,
regex  , a space, followed by `[0-9]+` one or more number followed by literal `:` followed by one or more space: `*`, if all such matched, then collect everything else than this matched pattern, ie. FIRST, SECOND,... so on because `-F` option determine it as field separator (FS) and $1, $2 .. so on is always else than FS. But the output needs nice look ie. has FS so that'd be `:` and it'd be awk variable definition -vOFS=':'

Comment: Thanks The Awk option worked. Could you explain what is (: *|$) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `[[:digit:]]` also with a ending asterisk, and leave only a space just after `OFS=` :

```
$ awk -F '[[:space:]][[:digit:]]*' '{$1=$1}1' OFS= file
FIRST:SECOND:THREE:FIVE:SIX
```

Comment: Triedn But no luck on this x='FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255'
echo $x | awk -F '[[:space:]][[:digit:]]*' '{$1=$1}1' OFS= 
FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255

Comment: @senthilnathan you have a file named `file` with content `FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255`, don't you?

Comment: senthil@ubuntu:~$ cat file
FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255
senthil@ubuntu:~$ awk -F '[[:space:]][[:digit:]]*' '{$1=$1}1' OFS= file
FIRST 1: SECOND 2: THREE 4: FIVE 255: SIX 255

Answer (score 0):

To get the output we want in idiomatic **awk**, we make the input field separator (with `-F`) contain all the stuff we want to eliminate (anchored with `:`), and make the output field separator (`OFS`) what we want it replaced with. The catch is that this won't eliminate the space and numbers at the end of the line, and for this we need to do something more. GNU’s implementation of **awk** will allow us to use a regular expression for the input record separator (`RS`), but we could just do a simple `sub()` with POSIX complaint **awk** as well.    Finally, force recalculation via `$1=$1`... the side effects for this pattern/statement are that the buffer will be recalculated doing FS/RS substitution for us, and that non-blank lines will take the default action -- which is to print.

```
gawk -F '[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*:[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=: -v RS='[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*\n' '$1=$1' file
```

Or:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*:[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=: '{ sub(/[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*$/, “”) } $1=$1' file
```

A **sed** implementation is fun but probably slower (because current versions of **awk** have better regex implementations).

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*:[[:space:]]/:/g; s/[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*$//' file
```

Or if POSIX character classes are not available...

```
sed 's/[\t ]*[0-9]*:[\t ]/:/g; s/[\t ]*[0-9]*[\t ]*$//' file
```

Something tells me that your “FIRST,  SECOND, THIRD...” might be more complicated, and might contain digits... in this case, you might want to experiment with replacing `*` with `+` for **awk** or with `\+` for **sed**.